# Write a For ... Endfor in the scratchpad on TI nspire CAS

Tags: calculator

I would like to write on the scratchpad a for loop (I don't want (because I don't know how) write a program on my calculator).

I have set in memory :

```
{15,27,35,59,14,71,56,15,25,61} -> c1
median(c1) -> m
```

And I want to execute :

```
For i,1,10 abs(c1[i] - m) Endfor
```

(for mathematicians :

∀ i ∈ [1, 10], calculate | c1[i] - m |

)

(in fact, the statement between For and Endfor isn't important).
My trouble is that on the scratchpad a statement can only be written on a single line. And it seems that the interpreter doesn't recognize it. I receive only Syntax error.

Is there a way to use For loop in the scratchpad ?

Comment: This doesn’t seem to be a math-related question. I vote for porting it to Stackexchange.

Comment: I have searched among the stackexhange I known which one had the most questions about the calculator TI nspire CAS. If you want to translate it to mathematics, read instead : __∀ i ∈ [1, 10], | c1[i] - m |__ and it's OK now ?

Comment: Algorithmic is a part of mathematics like arithmetic, geometry... It exists for more than twenty centuries. Loops are a part of mathematics.... Calculator usage too and there plenty of question about them here.

Comment: Would https://education.ti.com/html/webhelp/EG_TINspire/EN/content/m_programming/pr_using_loops.HTML bei helpful?

Comment: @Jens Schwaiger : the trouble is that on the scratchpad, you have not the ability to split the _For_ ... _Endfor_ in many lines. I search the way to put some of the samples of your your link in a single line to execute them.

Answer (score 0):

On my TI nspire CX 2 I can type the following in the scratchpad:

```
{15,27,35,59,14,71,56,15,25,61} -> c1
median(c1) -> m
For i,1,dim(c1): Disp abs(c1[i]-m): EndFor
```

(`dim` returns the length of the list, `Disp` is display, a.k.a. print)

It accepts `:` as line seperator.